# How to simulate double-touch on home button in iPhone 6 simulator (for Reachability)?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, simulator, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

In Apple's iPhone 6/+ simulator, is it possible to simulate a double tap on the home button that will move the contents down for "one-handed" operation (which Apple calls “Reachability”)?

Note: I'm not looking for the double-CLICK that brings up the task manager. Rather I'm looking into the software equivalent of simply touching the TouchID sensor twice in quick succession. This is only available on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

Comment: Very true, I simply didn't find the mentioned question!